# How to make value carry forward while looping?

Tags: vb.net

Thank you for your time spending at my question. My issue was, I was trying to make some records into BLACK & GRAY color based on some condition. But while doing, I am able to make BLACK color for all the records but leaving last record. Hence, I am missing to color-out the last record. I want to make all the records to BLACK in color. Here is my code. Please find it.

```
     For K = 1 To lvMergeGroup.ListItems.Count
     If ptrDataItem.ValidTo = "xxxxxxxxxxx" And ptrDataItem.StatusIndicator = "A" And ptrDataItem.UpdateTimeStamp = "xxxxxxxxxxx" Then 
             lvMergeGroup.ListItems.Item(K).ForeColor = System.Convert.ToUInt32(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black))  
     Else
             lvMergeGroup.ListItems.Item(K).ForeColor = System.Convert.ToUInt32(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Gray))
     End If
     Next K
```

Comment: what type of control and platform (winforms, webforms etc) are you working with?

Comment: Does your For statement work?  Try For K = 0 To lvMergeGroup.ListItems.Count-1

Comment: should be able to change for loop to a `For Each` loop as well, IE: `For Each item As ListItem in lvMergeGroup.ListItems` (assuming that lvMergeGroup.ListItems is a collection, which it would seem to be). Then use `item.ForeColoe = System.Convert.ToUInt32(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black))`

Comment: This part of your code `System.Convert.ToUInt32(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Gray))` just converts a colour to an integer and back again so should just be `Color.Gray`

Comment: For K=0 To lvMergeGroup.ListItems.Count-1 do not work for me. :(

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to

```
K = 0 To lvMergeGroup.ListItems.Count -1
```

Collections start at position 0

You could also use a for each loop, which will also give you access to each item individually.

```
For Each item In lvMergeGroup.ListItems
'code for 'item'
Next
```

Comment: For K=0 To lvMergeGroup.ListItems.Count-1 do not work for me. :( dmshow.

Comment: I declared K as static Long variable. When it loops inside, lvMergeGroup.ListItems.Item(K).ForeColor = System.Convert.ToUInt32(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black)), here the K value is changing in Item(K).ForeColor though it has to hold K=2 during second & K=3 for third loop & K=4 for fourth loop (actually, it will loop for 4 times I know).

Comment: You get to the item a little differently in a For Each.

Comment: Sorry hit the wrong button. Declare the type in the For Each statement. 'For Each item as Type In lvMergeGroup.ListItems'.